# Which DB (SQL) is better supported in Erlang?

Tags: database, erlang

What do you recommend me to use with Erlang -- MySQL or Postgres ? Which DB has better (more mature, more stable, faster) driver for Erlang ?

Answer (score 4):

The [Erlang ODBC interface](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/odbc/databases.html) can be used to connect to any database that has an ODBC driver. This is officially supported and can be used with both MySQL and Postgres. There is a 100% Erlang driver for Postgres called [PGSQL](http://frihjul.net/pgsql). This is not part of OTP and I am not sure about its quality.