# Erlang and MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, erlang

I have Erlang R14B04 (under centos) which should communicate with MS SQL Server 2008 (under windows). Can someone share experience in this unknown for me territory? As far as i know there no drivers like jdbc but for erlang? What driver should i use? I saw some posts that someone use odbc for this and got negative feedback. Can some one confirm it?

Comment: Erlang has ODBC support
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534447/which-db-sql-is-better-supported-in-erlang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use erlang odbcserver + unixodbc + freetds

Comment: thanks, that works for me. Googled working example of ODBC-hell setup under linux: http://www.savelono.com/linux/how-to-configure-linux-odbc-connections-for-ms-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

erlang ODBC works as good as the odbc driver on your platform does. This means that it is much better on windows than on any other platform, but still functional on the others.

Comment: I done some tests and "MUCH" better not so much, and difference in perfomance is absolutely disappears when i make pool.